# Why do i get the FB ID without an app request?

Tags: php, facebook

I debug the AppId with this snippet:

```
$this->facebook->getUser()
```

What happens:

- The User comes first to my App it outputs: "0"
- The User confirmed the App Request it outputs: "0000123456789"
- The User is deleting the Apprequest in his settings it still outputs: "0000123456789"

someone knows its possible Facebook still sending me his/her App ID...

Normally its ok but for me as developer its like hell to debug or test my application.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about app requests and not installation? `getUser()` returns the ID of the authenticated user, not the user to whom you've sent an app request.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk: your right getUser returns the ID of the auth.user. And isnt it right, that it should return nothing or 0 or NULL or whatever if the user is going to his settings and delete the app from his list?

Comment: or better whats the "normal" way for users who want to delete his app request ? i thought its done by deleting the app in his settings. or is it a new feature that the app keeping the requested information?

Comment: It should, and it does (eventually). Your Facebook SDK is relying on cookies set by Facebook to determine whether or not the user is logged in, and those cookies aren't always unset the way you expect. You might try destroying your session (or just try an API call with your access token with the expectation that it'll probably not work).

Answer (score 0):

These seems to be the defaults of the variables used. Make sure that your server address is whitelisted (by you) on facebook application page, and also make sure the configuration you use is correct.